# Mass import in Realm for Android

Tags: android, realm

I am looking at ways to migrate a SQLite DB in an android app to Realm. The DB has about 2000 records that need to be inserted upon first load. Is there a way to do this using the migration mechanism (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations) and createOrUpdateAllFromJson()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are not really used to insert data on first load. `RealmConfiguration` has a method called `initialData()` that is much more suited for this: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#initialData-io.realm.Realm.Transaction-

`createOrUpdateAllFromJson()` only makes sense if you can export you SQLite database to JSON. Most likely it will be much faster to just read the data directly from SQLite and insert them into Realm.

A more type-safe method would be to use `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` if you can somehow export your SQLite data to a in-memory object representation.